# Como converter o XSLT para um XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xslt

Tem dois arquivos um xslt e preciso de um xsd.
é possível converter/transformar o xslt em um xsd ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não faz sentido fazer isso porque eles tem propósitos diferentes:

**XSLT** é usando para "parsear" um `XML` transformando em outro `XML` (ou outro formato como `HTML`)

Leia mais aqui: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms759096(v=vs.85).aspx

**XSD** é um *schema* usado para validar a estrutura do `XML`, como nodes presentes, tipo de dados, etc.

Leia mais aqui: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms765537(v=vs.85).aspx

Portanto não tem sentido converter um para outro, porque são diferentes em estrutura e tem propósitos distintos.